# Developer story edits not saving

Tags: bug, developer-story

So, on my developer story, Profile picture was empty. I selected .jpg file with 460x460 and clicked on `Save`. Profile picture wasn't updated!

I went ahead, Edited my Personal Website address, Clicked `Save`. This dint get updated either.

Then i checked the console and found this:
[image]

Has this got something to do with my developer story profile info not updating?

I am talking about this part:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is ultimately from an issue with our Elasticsearch cluster going *crazy* last night. And it's still going crazy. We're looking into that and simultaneously looking into decoupling the dependency here (e.g. it's fine to sync up at night if something goes wrong) so you're unaware of issues that really shouldn't block you.

I'll update this when we have progress. For now, here's a pretty picture of Elastic being pissed off:
[image]

Comment: Well, thank you! If am correct at interpreting this image... It seems more than just `crazy` !!

Comment: @JonesJoseph Well 2932%CPU is spread over 32 CPUs so that averages around 91.6%

Comment: Oh, I've had this issue, just update your resume on stackoverflow, delete a bunch of the shards, and restart elasticsearch.

Comment: Why does elastic search have anything to do with the developer story and why is it so tightly coupled with such a module?  This makes no sense.

Comment: @JonH elasticsearch is how we index and search profiles on the employer side. Why *wouldn't* it have something to do with it? It shouldn't fail when there's a problem, and we're removing that. It was just an oversight on the dependency and quite minor to fix.